# how to get rid of "unkown scope" pull-down lists in 2010 Visual Studio/C++?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I just installed MS Visual Studio 2010, incl Visual C++, and by default at the top of each file editor window, are two pull-down lists, one with single item: "(Unknown Scope)" , and another one empty.

How to get rid of these lists altogether?

It may be "IntelliSense" - but, I disabled IntelliSense, and the lists are still there...

I also went through all the options, nothing else seems to help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I restarted Visual Studio and now they are gone.  Not sure why.

Comment: Does not help in my case... (VS 2008)